# face_grid and ggplot - color/colour argument error

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2

I am plotting a series of metrics against time, and using the `facet_grid` feature to plot each week separately, on one object.

`result_df`:

```
week metric_a    time_stamp
20   2567                   2015-09-30 09:04:29 
21   3567                   2015-10-03  17:36:39
22   3455                   2015-10-11 19:29:32

p = ggplot(aes(x='time_stamp',y='metric_a'),data=result_df) + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%H:%M")) + geom_line() + facet_grid('week',scales='free_x')
```

[image]

I now wish to use the `color` argument to illustrate the change between weeks.

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='time_stamp',y='metric_a',color="week"),data=result_df) + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%H:%M")) + geom_line() + facet_grid('week',scales='free_x')
```

However, this returns:

```
row, col = self.facets.facet_map[rowname]
```

Why is this an issue for the color argument and not the `facet_grid` argument?

Comment: Not sure how you are accessing ggplot2 from python. Is this using Rpy2?

Comment: @Thanks Mike. There is a python library - `http://ggplot.yhathq.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug further into the error trace and noticed there was a buried `KeyError`. I think found [this](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/issues/589) which showed that you can use `pd.categorical`.

Working edit required:

`result_df.week = result_df.week.astype("category")`